# Is there a way to create a screen using a shell script? (Centos)

Tags: centos

To be more specific,

On server reboot I need 20 screens to be created (I am hosting a massive Minecraft server network). I need the script that creates these screens, to be able to navigate to a directory and run a certain server-bootup script.

I found a method a few days ago, but that didn't keep the screen. This is really bugging me,
Thanks.

Comment: You might want to include more information, like some of the research you've already done, the programs you've already tried etc

Comment: // , Did you search for this first on search engines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
screen -d -m -S $name $command
```

Replacing $name with whatever you want to name that session and $command with whatever you want to run in that screen session.

Comment: How would i go about running a sh script? I tried using "sh Start.sh" for the command but it couldn't resume any screens when i tried to find it...

Comment: There is probably an issue with the command the shell script is trying to run.  Screen will exit once the command you've specified exits.  If there's a '&' to run a process in the background, remove it.